# which caching system to work with mpm_worker and mod_fcgid?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, mpm-worker

I was planning to use APC for my Apache Server based on mpm_worker and mod_fcgid but I found out that APC and also xCache doesn't work with mod_fcgid. so what do you suggest?

Comment: It works for me just fine, both of them. I used virtualmin to configure it and I added APC or xcache and it was working good, however APC seems to be more decent.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at comments [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/146864). I have tried it but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: It's all working fine. It's just not a shared cache. This is OK solution in many cases. It's not like it's not working. It's all fine working just with no cache sharing between instances.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. does menarche capable of sharing cache between instances? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I would have to find out and make tests. But I do believe if you map the RAM via file in /tmp/, it will be working OK, that the cache will be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works well for me. This one is with single process but it works stable with e.g. two.

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 1
FcgidMaxProcesses 1
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
```

php5.fcgi:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

php.ini:

extension=apc.so

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 512M
apc.num_files_hint = 1000
apc.user_entries_hint = 4096
apc.ttl = 0
apc.user_ttl = 0
apc.gc_ttl = 3600
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.filters = "apc\.php$"
apc.mmap_file_mask = "/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.use_request_time = 1
apc.stat = 1
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.report_autofilter = 0
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.localcache = 0
apc.localcache.size = 256M
apc.coredump_unmap = 0
apc.stat_ctime = 0
apc.canonicalize = 1
apc.lazy_functions = 1
apc.lazy_classes = 1
```